# Script block is not working in GSP page. Any solution?

Tags: grails, gsp

I have the script block in GSP page as shown in the code below. But the script block is not responding. Instead of printing hello in the console of the page, I get the error undefined operator $. What can be the reason?

**getSpecificQuestion.gsp**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
            $('.index').click(function() {
                console.log("hello")
            });
    </script>
    <title> Test </title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="question">
    <%= "question = $question"%>
</div>

<div id="indexButtons">

    <g:each in="${(1..<11)}" var="i">
        <input type="button" class="index" value="${i}"/>
    </g:each>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you check if you have the jquery plugin? in BuildConfig.groovy

Comment: Yeap Neoryder, I have jquery plugin installed.

Comment: Put the `$('.index').click...` inside `$(document).ready...`

Comment: Tried that as well, still no luck

Comment: does the gsp use layout

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your gsp did not include any jquery in it so it complained about the missing $

Make sure that you include jquery in your gsp before the your script block. If you are using the resources plugin you can do something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <r:require module="jQuery1111"/>
  <r:script>
    $(function() {
      $('.index').click(function() {
        console.log("hello")
      });  
    })
  </r:script>
  <title> Test </title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="question">
  <%= "question = $question"%>
</div>

<div id="indexButtons">

  <g:each in="${(1..<11)}" var="i">
    <input type="button" class="index" value="${i}"/>
  </g:each>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using the  tag will render your javascript at the bottom of the page after all the DOM elements have been rendered and ready to be manipulated by the scripts.